# Should plugin bug reports and issues be closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[RedactorStyles Plugin Not Working](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/redactorstyles-plugin-not-working)

This question is specifically about a 3rd party plugin to Craft, is not about Craft itself and can only *really* be fixed/addressed by the plugin owner.

So is the Craft SE a good place for this type of question, or should they be closed ass off-topic/bug reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, such questions should be closed. You can flag the question to be closed because it's "Off Topic"... Then you'll see these options:

[image]

Comment: Ah good spot! I didn't see the '...CMS or plugins' part, must have brushed over that. Thanks Anna.